# image uploading using advance php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I am working on oops based project in php when I upload an image it is not uploade with information that I want to upload with this image. Here i connect the controller page I create object for uploading the image and information in database.

Code for html page

```
<?php
include('include/control.php');
include('include/connect.php');
error_reporting(0);
if(count($_FILES) > 0){
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
        $i=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $j=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$objectNew=new add;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $info1=$_POST['info1'];
 $info2=$_POST['info2'];
 $info3=$_POST['info3'];
 $info4=$_POST['info4'];
 $info5=$_POST['info5'];

 $imagetype=$i;
 $imageData=$j;
  $ob=$objectNew->addInfo($imagetype,$imagedata,$info1,$info2,$info3,$info4,$info5);
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
add info<br />
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="info1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="info2" /><br />
<input type="text" name="info3" /><br />
<input type="text" name="info4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="info5" /><br />
<input type="file" name="image"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for controller

```
 function addInfo($imagetype,$imagedata,$info1,$info2,$info3,$info4,$info5)
   {
       $addI=$this->conn->prepare('insert into `addinfo` (imagetype,image,info1,info2,info3,info4,info5) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ');
       $addI->bind_param("sbsssss",$imagetype,$imagedata,$info1,$info2,$info3,$info4,$info5) ;
       $addI->execute();
   }
```

Comment: so... what "information" are you missing?

Comment: You should remove addslashes from $i=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); and convert the 'image' column from your table to BLOB type. Also $imageData = $i and $imagetype = $j;

Comment: I think also that you need to use http://de1.php.net/move_uploaded_file to upload the file in a folder

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion.
You could add "required" attribute to your inputs so it won't be submitted if its empty.
This works on latest browser

your code

```
<input type="text" name="info1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="info2" /><br />
```

can be

```
<input type="text" name="info1" required /><br />
<input type="text" name="info2" required /><br />
```